# APOP Authentication withe libcurl

Tags: c++, c, libcurl

Has anyone had any success with libcurl and POP3 with APOP authentication?
I had success with the clear authentication but not with APOP since the library
sends the USER command almost immediately after making a connection.

How do I make libcurl send APOP command and stop it sending USER command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libcurl currently doesn't support APOP. You need to dive in and make it so!

Comment: I see. Thank you very much! It seems that way.